# Laravel 6 using Axios to upload image with vuejs-clipper

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, image-uploading, laravel-6

I want to implement a function to upload a cropable profile photo using [vuejs-clipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-clipper). I got the frontend set which uses the `clipper-upload` & `clipper-fixed` to upload and view/cropping the image. What I expect if for the cropped image to be uploaded as the profile photo.

But when I tried to submit my form, no image file was sent and I think that's because of the input in the `clipper-upload`'s template has no `name` attribute. I've tried again after manually adding the `name` attribute to the file input through web inspector, which got through and updated the user's profile photo.

The problem here is that the image uploaded is not cropped but the whole of the image. So I thought of using Axios to post the image, which I then got a 405 (Method not allowed) error message. Even if the post might work in Axios, I fell like the image uploaded is still the whole of the image (not cropped) since I've selected the element by id and pull its file content.

How can I upload a cropped photo using vuejs-clipper? Preferably using Laravel and Vue solutions without Axios if possible because I want to do stuff to the file in the Laravel controller.

**Profile Photo's Modal - Laravel Blade**

```
<div id="vue-profilePhotoUpload" class="modal-content">
    <form action="{{action('DashboardTalentController@profilePhoto', $user->talent->id)}}" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">

        @csrf
        @method('PUT')

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Update Your Profile Picture</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" id="vue-profilePhoto">
            <clipper-upload id="clipperUpload" v-model="imgURL" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2" :check=true>upload image
            </clipper-upload>
            <clipper-fixed class="my-clipper" :src="imgURL">
                <div class="placeholder" slot="placeholder">No image</div>
            </clipper-fixed>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="vue-profilePhotoUploadBtn" type="button" v-on:click="uploadImage"
                class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

**Profile Photo - JavaScript**

```
    import Vue from "vue";
    import VuejsClipper from "vuejs-clipper";
    import VueRx from "vue-rx";

    Vue.use(VuejsClipper, {
        components: {
            clipperBasic: true,
            clipperPreview: true,
            clipperFixed: true,
            clipperUpload: true
        }
    });
    Vue.use(VueRx);

new Vue({
    el: "#vue-profilePhotoUpload",
    data: {
        imgURL: '',
    },
    methods: {
        getResult: function () {
            const canvas = this.$refs.clipper.clip(); //call component's clip method
            this.resultURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1); //canvas->image
        },
        'uploadImage': function () {
            document.getElementById('vue-profilePhotoUploadBtn').onclick = function () {
                var data = new FormData()
                var imageInput = document.getElementById('clipperUpload').lastChild
                var uploadImage = imageInput.files[0]
                data.append('file', uploadImage)

                const config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                };
                axios.post('/talent/dashboard/1/profilephoto', data, config).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }).catch(function(err) {console.log(err)});
            }
        }
    }
});
```